# How to set 777 permission on a particular folder?

Tags: php, permissions

How to set 777 permission on folder.

- i need to Set the permission of the following folder to 777:
  admin\includes\module_installation

I do no idea how to set the permission 777 on particular folder in window 7??

Please help me how can I set it? 
I am using windows 7.

Comment: It must be for `linux` you can skip that step for win 7.

Comment: See also [In a PHP / Apache / Linux context, why exactly is chmod 777 dangerous?](/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`777` is a permission in Unix based system with full read/write/execute permission to owner, group and everyone.. in general we give this permission to assets which are not much needed to  be hidden from public on a web server, for example images..

You said `I am using windows 7.` if that means that your web server is Windows based then you should login to that and right click the folder and set permissions to `everyone` and if you are on a windows client and server is unix/linux based then use some ftp software and in the parent directory right click and change the permission for the folder.

If you want permission to be set on `sub-directories` too then usually their is option to set permission recursively use that.

And, if you feel like doing it from command line the use putty and login to server and go to the parent directory `includes` and write the following command

```
chmod 0777 module_installation/
```

for recursive

```
chmod -R 0777 module_installation/
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: how chmod works for windows 7

Comment: chmod is a unix based command not for windows. If you want to set permissions in windows you may use the procedure I wrote in the 2nd para `....your web server is Windows based then you should login to that and right click the folder and set permissions to everyone and if you are on a windows client and server is unix/linux based then...`

Comment: if that doesn't work try to see if some configuration of the server is blocking the delivery of the files for a specific path

Comment: Nube question, what is the the `0` in front of `0777`, I thought `777` was suffice?

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to set permissions to 777 is to connect to Your server through FTP Application like FileZilla, right click on folder, module_installation, and click Change Permissions - then write 777 or check all permissions.

Answer (score 6):

1. Right click the folder, click on Properties.
2. Click on the Security tab
3. Add the name `Everyone` to the user list.

Comment: hello ErJab.  in properties there is only 3 tabs like General,Previous Version,Customization i am not found any option like "security tab" please help me

Comment: You can add one user there.

Answer (score 0):

go to FileZilla and select which folder you will be give 777 permission, then right click set permission 777 and select check box, then ok.

Comment: Please read the existing answers before resurrecting an old thread. That was [already suggested several months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389789/104223).