# PHP fopen - Write a variable to a txt file

Tags: php, fopen

I've checked this and its not working for me !
[PHP Write a variable to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046684/php-write-a-variable-to-a-txt-fil)

So this is my code,please take a look ! I want to write all the content of the variable to the file. But when i run the code,its only write the last line of the content !

```
<?php
$re = '/<li><a href="(.*?)"/';
$str = '
<li><a href="http://www.example.org/1.html"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.example.org/2.html"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.example.org/3.html"</a></li> ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo '<div id="pin" style="float:center"><textarea class="text" cols="110" rows="50">';
// Print the entire match result

foreach($matches[1] as $content)
  echo $content."\r\n";
$file = fopen("1.txt","w+");
echo fwrite($file,$content);
fclose($file);
?>
```

When i open 1.txt,its only show me

> http://www.example.org/3.html

It's should be

```
http://www.example.org/1.html
http://www.example.org/2.html
http://www.example.org/3.html
```

Am i doing wrong anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
foreach($matches[1] as $content)
     echo $content."\r\n";
```

only iterates over the array and makes `$content` the last element (you have no `{}` so it is a one liner).

Simple demo of your issue, https://eval.in/806352.

You could use use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) though.

```
fwrite($file,implode("\n\r", $matches[1]));
```

You also could simplify this by using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Per the manual:

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

So you could just do:

```
$re = '/<li><a href="(.*?)"/';
$str = '
<li><a href="http://www.example.org/1.html"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.example.org/2.html"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.example.org/3.html"</a></li> ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo '<div id="pin" style="float:center"><textarea class="text" cols="110" rows="50">';
file_put_contents("1.txt", implode("\n\r", $matches[1]));
```

Comment: Great, please accept answer when time passes. Also take a look at update.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you can use [file_put_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with `FILE_APPEND` flag, also, don't use regex to parse `HTML`, use an `HTML` parser like [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), i.e.:

```
$html = '
<li><a href="http://www.example.org/1.html"</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.org/2.html"</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.org/3.html"</a></li>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html); // @ suppress DOMDocument warnings
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//li/a/@href') as $href) 
{
    file_put_contents("file.txt", "$href->nodeValue\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```