# Save input data in php file (No DB)

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to save input data in `php` file without using any database?

Something like:

```
echo " inputted text.. ";
```

or

```
$text = "Text..";
```

Comment: maybe you want `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP fopen - Write a variable to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217732/php-fopen-write-a-variable-to-a-txt-file)

Comment: Txt file json file cookies, I think there's no other way

Answer (score 0):

Use fwrite, very easy :

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'this is my database without database :p ');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: I want <form> :/ And edit php file, not txt (And not all text..)

Comment: you mean that you want to edit a file.php using another PHP file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with a form, and extract some variables into a file you can use:

Your Form in form.html

```
<form action="recipient.php" method="POST">

  INPUT1: <input type="text" name="text1" id="input1"><br/>
  INPUT2: <input type="text" name="text2" id="input2"><br/>
  FILENAME: <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename">

  <button type="submit">Send now</button>

</form>
```

Your PHP recipient.php - without any validation checks:

```
<?php
$varA = "\$varA = ".$_POST['input1'].";"; // put your string into varible $varA
$varB = "\$varB = ".$_POST['input1'].";"; // put your string into varible $varA
$fileName = $_POST['filename']; // set a filename from form field

$text = $varA ." ". $varB;  // add all together 

$filepath = fopen('/var/www/html/'.$fileName.'.php', 'w+'); // set filepath and fopen to new PHP-file
fwrite($filepath, '<?php '. $text); // write text as PHP-file
fclose($filepath); // close file
?>
```

If you haven't read about them yet check [HTML-Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).
You might also want to look into [arrays and serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize).
But apart from that I highly recommend to have a look into [Databases (PDO)](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) - it safes you time and is much more secure.