# how to add the audio name in database and audio file in folder?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I tried to add the audio file into the folder and its name to database but file doesnot upload into the folder but it is added into the database.Following is my Controller:

```
public function add_audio(){


            $config['upload_path'] = './songs/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|3gp|mpeg|mp4';

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('output');






            $data['audio'] = $_FILES['output']['name'];



            $this->load->model('main');
            $query = $this->main->insert('audio',$data);



            if($query = TRUE){


            $this->load->view('admin/success');

        }else{


        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }//end else
    }//end function
```

my folder name is songs.and database name is audio.Database is uploading the audio name but not the folder..so please help

Comment: is your `songs` folder at root directory??

Comment: yes...it is in root

Comment: Did you set the folder permission to 777??

Comment: I dont know what is that...and where to set the permission..i am new to the programming so would you help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set permission 777 to your upload directory. go to your root directory first and then use below command:

```
chmod 0777 songs/
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389765/how-to-set-777-permission-on-a-particular-folder) to know more to change folder permission.

Comment: i didn't set the permission level for the image it works fine but do i have to set permission level to audio files?

Comment: you provide me the code but where to paste it.....please help...i am running windows and xampp as my server

Comment: @sudeepacharya it was actually a command to run on terminal....if it worked for image then it should work for songs folder too! try debugging...
If you want code then try putting `chmod('songs/', 0777);` this line before your `$this->upload->do_upload()`