# Laravel Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\File::delete()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I made a method which allows the user to update their profile picture. I also added a function which deletes their old profile picture if they update to a new one. But i get an error saying `Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\File::delete()`.

What is causing this? In the code below it makes perfect sense for me. I hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance

Code: 
UserController.php

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request) {

    $this->middleware('auth');

    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = Auth::user()->username . time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->fit(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();

        //Verwijderd vorige foto
        if ($user->avatar != 'default.jpg') {
            $path = 'uploads/avatars/';
            $lastpath = Auth::user()->Avatarpath;
            File::delete(public_path($path . $lastpath));
        }
    }

    return view('user.profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
```

Route: `Route::post('{username}/profile', 'UserController@update_avatar');`

The form that is supposed to do this.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col l12 m12 s12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile" method="POST">
                        <input type="file" name="avatar">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-primary" value="Change profile">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Changing the picture works just fine. If I reload the page the profile picture is updated but it doesn't delete the old one.

Comment: try to print the $lastpath to see if it contains a / infront then you need to remove it, else while concatenating 'uploads/avatars//someath will occurr

Comment: @Exprator I added a `dd($lastpath)` after the code where $lastpath is defined, but after I tried the code that Dharmesh send, It just refreshed the page. Without even changing the profile picture

Answer (score 3):

> try this. does this help.

```
 public function update_avatar(Request $request) {

        $this->middleware('auth');

        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = Auth::user()->username . time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->fit(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();

            //Verwijderd vorige foto
            if ($user->avatar != 'default.jpg') {
                 $path = public_path('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'avatars'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.Auth::user()->Avatarpath);
                  if (file_exists($path)) {
                    unlink($path);
                  }
            }
        }

        return view('user.profile', array('user' => $user));
    }
```

Comment: Permission denied, So its something with the right of the folder. How do i change this so this works? This program needs to be allowed to change stuff inside that folder.

Comment: see for permission issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389765/how-to-set-777-permission-on-a-particular-folder