# Locally, image gets uploaded but when I upload WordPress website on a server, the image does not get uploaded

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing advertisement website in WordPress. Locally, it works fine, but when I upload website on a server, it cannot upload the image. It is showing "error".

I do not understand what is the problem because locally image upload works, but on server it doesn't.

I googled and try to solve problem using this link http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/http-image-error
but problem is still not solved.

[image]

Comment: I think its a folder permission issue. please check folder permission in server.

Comment: how can i change permission on server

Comment: what type of server you use now? is it linux or windows? you can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389765/how-to-set-777-permission-on-a-particular-folder

Comment: its linux server

Comment: Then login to server using ssh key then go to wp-content folder, then use this command  sudo chmod -R 777

Answer (score 1):

@alex 644 for the files and 755 for the folders should be fine. No need for 777 on a live server.